# github.getOctokit(myToken) returns empty values for GitHub Action in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, github, github-actions, octokit-js

I'm trying to make a GitHub action that runs when someone comments on a pull request (I'm using issue_comment).

In my `index.js`, I'm running the following lines:

```
const core = require("@actions/core");
const github = require("@actions/github");
.
.
.
const myToken = core.getInput("github-token");
const octokit = github.getOctokit(myToken);
core.info(JSON.stringify(octokit));
```

and the output is

```
{
  "log": {},
  "rest": {
    "actions": {},
    "activity": {},
    "apps": {},
    "billing": {},
    "checks": {},
    "codeScanning": {},
    "codesOfConduct": {},
    "emojis": {},
    "enterpriseAdmin": {},
    "gists": {},
    "git": {},
    "gitignore": {},
    "interactions": {},
    "issues": {},
    "licenses": {},
    "markdown": {},
    "meta": {},
    "migrations": {},
    "orgs": {},
    "packages": {},
    "projects": {},
    "pulls": {},
    "rateLimit": {},
    "reactions": {},
    "repos": {},
    "search": {},
    "secretScanning": {},
    "teams": {},
    "users": {}
  }
}
```

Without pulls being populated, I can't merge the pull request. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was using syntax from I believe, v4. V5 introduces octokit.rest.pulls, so my problem wasn't shown in this problem as octokit is not meant to be printed.